# How to Delay automatic opening of Modal Dialog box window in JQuery 1.5.x?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, dialog, modal-dialog

The following dialog box works nicely when clicked upon:

```
<a href="#" onclick="jQuery('#dialogX').dialog('open');
             return false"><? echo __("Under Construction")?></a>
```

The javascript sitting at the bottom of the html triggers the action:

```
jQuery("#dialogX").dialog({bgiframe: true, autoOpen: false, modal: true});
```

Now, what I would wish, is to have the dialog popup after say 2 seconds (insterad of immediately). I saw the option autoOpen and when setting the value to 2000 instead of false, that helas dit not work: it opens immediately. What am I missing?

Thanks very much for your hints and wish you a nice weekend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout **It executes a code snippet or a function after specified delay.**

So

```
setTimeout(function(){ showDialog() }, 2000);
```

should solve your problem.

Also have a look at the `.delay( n )` method. http://api.jquery.com/delay/

```
$('.notice').fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut('slow');
```

Comment: @ArtWorkAD +1 thanks I'm still busy implementing is correctly ( not succesfull yet) the last line looks elegantly short, with the fade effect... that would be awesome...

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, i added `setTimeout(function(){ showDialog() }, 2000);` but something is missing...  perhaps the word `showDialog` should be replaced with something else?

Comment: I've setup a demo for you: http://jsfiddle.net/v3XPx/6/ you have to put the showDialog in timeout without the '()'

Comment: @Beautifully @Awesome @Works! @Thanks @ArtWorkAD  jipiiiiieie

Comment: @ArtWorkAD, one tiny last thing: how to get "autoOpen:true" orso working with this timed example? in other words make it automatically load for question after a set amount of seconds. (underconstruction feedback dialog). Thank you very much.

Comment: AutoOpen is enabled by default, http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/ at the Bottom is a Description. Is that what you mean by Auto open?