# Can delay() be used with jQuery UI dialog.open()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have this code inline in document ready

```
if($.cookie('form_seen') == null) { 
  $("#dialog_form").dialog("open");
}
```

I know how to use setTimeout like [How to Delay automatic opening of Modal Dialog box window in JQuery 1.5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603526/how-to-delay-automatic-opening-of-modal-dialog-box-window-in-jquery-1-5-x) so no need to post a setTimeout example.

I wondered for my personal education, what the correct syntax would be if I wanted to use .delay instead of setTimeout

```
if($.cookie('form_seen') == null) { 
  $("#dialog_form").delay(5000).dialog("open");
}
```

or similar

In this case it is not obvious what I would gain since I would have to wrap `$("#dialog_form").dialog("open");` in the function called by setTimeout so no need for closures or finding $(this) back, but in other situations I can imagine chaining being smarter.
Comments to pros and cons are very welcome

Comment: Not advisable, delay is only for pauses between queued effects. What does setTimeout not give you?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if($.cookie('form_seen') == null) { 
  $("#dialog_form")
    .delay(5000)
    .queue(function(next){
        $(this).dialog("open");
        next(); // take this function out of queue a.k.a dequeue a.k.a notify done
                // so the next function on the queue continues execution...
    })
}
```

OR

```
if($.cookie('form_seen') == null) { 
  $("#dialog_form")
    .delay(5000)
    .queue(function(){
        $(this)
            .dialog("open")
            .dequeue(); // take this function out of queue a.k.a dequeue a.k.a notify done
                        // so the next function on the queue continues execution...
    })
}
```

Comment: Not understandable. What does next() do?

Comment: @mplungjan: `next()` will be passed the `.dequeue()` function, which will ensure the queue keeps moving. That is, after the queued function has been executed, it should be taken out of the queue, so the execution of the queue can continue. You might as well do `$(this).dialog("open").dequeue();`

Comment: Ok thanks - I will use setTimeout instead since I really do not see any advantage with this more complex code, but you answered the question