# How to use delay() with each()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, delay, slidedown

```
$("#home #oneTool").prepend($(".userInfo.module"));

var topVal = $(".userInfo.module").height();
$(".userInfo.module").hide();
$(".userInfo.module").slideDown(3000);

$("#home #oneTool div.divspot").each(function(){
   var newVal = topVal + parseInt($(this).css('top'));
   $(this).css('top',newVal);
});
```

The `.userInfo.module` is present above all `div.divspot`s...

Since i'm using slideDown, the each function needs to be delayed, so that the `div.divspot`s could also slidedown smoothly.. (will delay be helpful?)

**Note:** All `div.divspot`s are absolutely positioned

Comment: Here is a possible contender if delay cannot be used directly. setTimeout or delay plus queue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641222/can-delay-be-used-with-jquery-ui-dialog-open

Comment: What happens if you move the slidedown to after the each? It is hidden, so is it even showing the slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, slideDown takes as a parameter a function to call after it's done. http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

Props to another answerer who realized what you were asking and a #fail to me for not reading your question properly.

That being said, for a method that does not have a callback after completion, here are a couple of options.

Two options:

1. Use queue
2. Use setTimeout

Use queue:

http://api.jquery.com/queue/

```
$(".userInfo.module").fooThatTakes(3000).queue(function() {
  $("#home #oneTool div.divspot").each(function(){
    var newVal = topVal + parseInt($(this).css('top'));
    $(this).css('top',newVal);
  });
});
```

Use setTimeout.

```
var delay = 3000;
$(".userInfo.module").fooThatTakes(delay);
t = setTimeout(afterFoo, delay);

function afterFoo() {
  $("#home #oneTool div.divspot").each(function(){
    var newVal = topVal + parseInt($(this).css('top'));
    $(this).css('top',newVal);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, then you want to run your `each` function after the `slideDown` is complete. If that's right, then you can use a callback to the `slideDown` function:

```
$(".userInfo.module").slideDown(3000, function() {
    //Your each function
});
```

The callback will run upon completion of the animation.

Comment: oh no.. i want to run the slide down and the each function parallely